# How to handle orientation change using fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-orientation

I now have 2 fragment, one fragment handle portrait mode then another handle landscape mode. But the problem is that when rotate from portrait to landscape then back to portrait. It will not show the same thing that show on the first portrait mode. Is there any code that can solve this problem?

This code is inside the fragment holder:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.frag_holder);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    final Fragment fragment = Frag.newInstance(); //Portrait layout
    final Fragment fragment2 = Frag2.newInstance(); //Landscape layout

    int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation; //check whether is it portrait or landscape


    if(orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Fragment fragTAG = fm.findFragmentByTag(TAG_P);
        if(fragTAG == null){
            Log.i("test","test");
                fm.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.fragPlaceHolder, fragment, TAG_P)
                        .commit(); //Portrait
        }
        else{
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragPlaceHolder,fragTAG).commit();
        }

    }
    if(orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
        Fragment fragTAG = fm.findFragmentByTag(TAG_L);
        if(fragTAG == null){
                fm.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.fragPlaceHolder, fragment2, TAG_L)
                        .commit(); //Landscape
        }
        else{
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragPlaceHolder,fragTAG).commit();
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You need to post the code that causes problem first.

Comment: The only real solution to your problem: You shouldn't have different Fragments for different orientations. That's not how things are supposed to work on Android.

Comment: @Xaver Kapeller then is there any other ways to do it, with the same result coming out. I just want the same thing show on both portrait even if you rotate.

Comment: @Zheng yes there is. As I already said: Don't use different Fragments for different orientations. That is what's causing your problems in the first place.  Use just one for both orientations and take advantage of Androids resource qualifier system to change resources like the layout etc when the orientation is changed.

Answer (score 6):

Step 1: 
Add Config changes in your activity

```
    <activity android:name=".ui.createtasks.CreateTaskActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden" > </activity>
```

Step 2:
   Add your edit text values to `onSaveInstanceState`

```
 @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
     outState.putCharSequence(KEY_TITLE, et_text.getText().toString());
 }
```

Step 3:
 Get your Saved edit text values through `onViewStateRestored`

```
    @Override
public void onViewStateRestored(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);

    String savedTitle = null;
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        savedTitle = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_TITLE);
        et_text.setText(savedTitle);

    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry its a manifest not activity (Step 1: Add Config changes in your activity)
Step 1: Add Config changes in your manifest

Comment: This is not useful when you have different layout for each orientation. Setting `android:configChanges` in the Manifest will prevent recreation of activity, and corresponding layout won't load.

Answer (score 1):

You can either call `setRetainInstance(True);` in the onCreate() methods in both Fragments.

Or

to create a headless-Fragment(a Fragment with no UI) to cache data.

A third option will be to use `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` to cache data and re-display the data by using `Bundle savedInstanceState` in the onCreateView() method.

Comment: I have try the first one but when the phone rotate back to portrait layout. It destroy the first time portrait layout. And what you mean by headless-Fragment?

Comment: None of the advice here is correct. `setRetainInstance()` is not to preserve the data, its for keeping the `Fragment` instance around when you actually need to do that. Aside from that this won't work for the op because he has different `Fragment` for each orientation and presumably only one is attached for each. The `Activity` can't retain an instance of the `Fragment` is not attached. A `Fragment` without UI defeats the purpose of having  a `Fragment` in the first place, definitely don't do that. And it off course won't fix anything in this situation.

Comment: The only real answer is your third option. And if done right this would happen automatically for the most part. The only real solution is not to have two different `Fragment`s for different orientations. That's what's causing the problems in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

When there is activity rotation, the activity closed and reopen the onDestroy and onCreate are called.
if you want to save data and reload it in the other rotation you can do it with onSaveInstanceState method:

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
```

for example:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("name", "David");
    outState.putInt("age", 17);
}
```

and reload the data in the onCreate

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    …
    if(savedInstanceState != null)
    {
         savedInstanceState.getString("name");
         savedInstanceState.getInt("age");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add code in manifest file

```
<activity
        android:name=".file_name"//add your activity name
        android:label="label" //add label
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```