# Keep the Fragment After Screen is Rotated

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, screen-orientation

I think stackoverflow already has a lot this kind of topic, but I still can't understand.

The thing is, I want to keep the fragment and its data when the screen is rotated and the internet is inactive.

So the scenario is:

1. Load Main Activity
2. Turn off the internet
3. Rotate the screen
4. Check if the data still exist

The problem of my code is when user rotate the screen and the internet is inactive, it won't load because as I know it will call the setShow() in View Model, which is will hit the API.

I don't allowed to use something like android:configChange, or setRetainInstance. Only 
something like onSaveInstanceState.

Here's my MainActivity.java:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private Fragment pageContent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);

        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_movies);
        } else {
            pageContent = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, "fragment");

            loadFragment(pageContent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_movies:
                Bundle movieBundle = new Bundle();
                movieBundle.putBoolean("isFavorite", false);
                fragment = new MovieFragment();
                fragment.setArguments(movieBundle);
                pageContent = fragment;
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_tvshow:
                Bundle tvBundle = new Bundle();
                tvBundle.putBoolean("isFavorite", false);
                fragment = new TvShowFragment();
                fragment.setArguments(tvBundle);
                pageContent = fragment;
                break;
        }
        return loadFragment(fragment);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .putFragment(outState, "fragment", pageContent);
    }

    private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        if (fragment != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

MovieFragment.java (it's the same as TvShowFragment).

```java
public class MovieFragment extends Fragment {

    private ShowAdapter adapter;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private ShowViewModel showViewModel;
    private FavoriteHelper favoriteHelper;
    private Boolean isFavorite;

    public MovieFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getActivity() != null) {
            showViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(ShowViewModel.class);
            showViewModel.getShows().observe(this, getShow);
        }
    }

    private Observer<ArrayList<Show>> getShow = new Observer<ArrayList<Show>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(ArrayList<Show> shows) {
            if (shows != null) {
                adapter.setData(shows);
                showLoading(false);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        this.isFavorite = bundle.getBoolean("isFavorite");
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_show, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        showLoading(true);

        adapter = new ShowAdapter();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        favoriteHelper = FavoriteHelper.getInstance(getActivity());

        RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_show);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        showViewModel.setShows("movie");
    }

    private void showLoading(Boolean state) {
        if (state) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

And ShowViewModel.java

```java
public class ShowViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private static final String API_KEY = "API_KEY";
    private MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Show>> listShows = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    private ArrayList<Show> listItems = new ArrayList<>();
    private Show show;

    public void setShows(final String type) {
        listItems.clear();
        String url = String.format("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/%s?api_key=%s&language=en-US", type, API_KEY);

        client.get(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                try {
                    String result = new String(responseBody);
                    JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(result);
                    JSONArray results = responseObject.getJSONArray("results");

                    for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject shows = results.getJSONObject(i);
                        Show show = new Show();
                        show.setTitle(shows.getString(type.equals("movie") ? "title" : "name"));
                        show.setImage(shows.getString("poster_path"));
                        show.setBackdropImage(shows.getString("backdrop_path"));
                        show.setSynopsis(shows.getString("overview"));
                        show.setRelease(shows.getString(type.equals("movie") ? "release_date" : "first_air_date"));
                        listItems.add(show);
                    }
                    listShows.postValue(listItems);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                Log.d("onFailure", error.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    public LiveData<ArrayList<Show>> getShows() {
        return listShows;
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48127552/1371792)?

Comment: I'm not allowed using android:configChanges.

Answer (score 0):

create a BaseActivity and then keep the savedInstanceState. 
example :

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

protected Bundle savedInstanceState;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.savedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;
}
```

and extend this BaseActivity from your activity class and then check the parent savedInstanceState is it null or not. example :

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private Fragment pageContent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);

    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        pageContent = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, "fragment");
    }
    else {
        // load your fragment..
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.navigation_movies:
            Bundle movieBundle = new Bundle();
            movieBundle.putBoolean("isFavorite", false);
            fragment = new MovieFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(movieBundle);
            pageContent = fragment;
            break;
        case R.id.navigation_tvshow:
            Bundle tvBundle = new Bundle();
            tvBundle.putBoolean("isFavorite", false);
            fragment = new TvShowFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(tvBundle);
            pageContent = fragment;
            break;
    }
    return loadFragment(fragment);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .putFragment(outState, "fragment", pageContent);
}

private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    if (fragment != null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment)
                .commit();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: Unfortunately it has no effect.